# PHP: 404 with CodeIgniter controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter

In learning CodeIgniter, I am at a roadblock while following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4PvPKRivZM). I am getting a 404 not found when calling the "`login_validation`" function of the "`Main`" class controller.

> The requested URL /ci/main/login_validation was not found on this server.

### The "main" controller class and functions

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->login();
    }

    public function login() {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function login_validation() {   // NOT FOUND?
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5'); //md5 value encryption

        echo "ok"; //check if function executes

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            redirect('main/members');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }

}
```

### Relevant code in the View PHP file

```
<?php 

    echo form_open('main/login_validation');  // NOT FOUND?

    echo validation_errors();

    echo "<p>Email: ";
    echo form_input('email');
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>Password: ";
    echo form_password('password');
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>";
    echo form_submit('login_submit','Login');
    echo "</p>";

    echo form_close();

?>
```

### .htaccess code

Directory is on localhost

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/ci/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: does /ci/main/ work the index method? or in other words is it finding the Main controller at all?

Comment: yes, "main" has been set as the default controller, so /ci works the index method

Comment: oh, mine is Welcome, anyway does login() work?

Comment: it seems to, because login calls view('login'), which shows up with the forms etc

Comment: Try this 
/ci/index.php/main/login_validation
instead of 
/ci/main/login_validation

Comment: @SamarHaider That worked! Thank you! Why isn't my current route working? Could it be because of incorrect .htaccess?

Comment: @bsapaka: write your .htaccess code here

Comment: @SamarHaider htaccess code posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below one code for .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
#IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```